# std::function: cannot convert derived class parameter to base class parameter

Tags: c++, parameters, dom-events, c++17, std-function

I'm attempting to mimic JavaScript style `Event/EventTarget` operations in C++ (C++17).
I have an `Event` base class that works as needed, and a `KeyboardEvent` class that inherits from `Event`.
My `EventTarget.addEventListener` function stores `EventObjects` in a vector that can be called with `dispatchEvent`.

I am able to use `addEventListener` to store callback functions using a `Event` parameter, e.g. `onGenericEvent(Event event)`.
However, I am unable to use `addEventListener` to add callback functions that take a `KeyboardEvent` parameter, e.g. `onKeyDown(KeyboardEvent event)`.

I was expecting `std::function<void(Event)>` to accept `KeyboardEvent` since it inherits from `Event` but I receive a compilation error:

> ERROR: cannot convert 'void (*)(KeyboardEvent)' to 'std::function<void(Event)>'

How should I proceed?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


class Event {
public:
    Event(std::string _type, void* _pointer) {
        type = _type;
        pointer = _pointer;
    }
    std::string type;
    void* pointer;
};


struct EventObject {
    std::string type;
    std::function<void(Event)> listener;
    void* pointer;
};

class EventTarget {
public:
    static void addEventListener(std::string type, std::function<void(Event)> listener, void* pointer){
        EventObject eventObj;
        eventObj.type = type;
        eventObj.listener = listener;
        eventObj.pointer = pointer;
        events.push_back(eventObj);
    }
    static void dispatchEvent(Event event){
        for (unsigned int n = 0; n < events.size(); ++n) {
            if (event.type == events[n].type && event.pointer == events[n].pointer) {
                events[n].listener(event);
            }
        }
    }
    static std::vector<EventObject> events;
};
std::vector<EventObject> EventTarget::events;


class KeyboardEvent : public Event {
public:
    KeyboardEvent(std::string _type, void* _pointer) : Event(_type, _pointer) {
        key = "random key";
    }
    std::string key;
};


class App
{
public:
    static void onGenericEvent(Event event) {
        printf("event.type = %s \n", event.type.c_str());
    }
    
    static void onKeyDown(KeyboardEvent event) {
        printf("event.type = %s \n", event.type.c_str());  // print Event class property
        printf("event.key = %s \n", event.key.c_str());    // print KeyboardEvent class property
    }
};


int main() {
    App* app = new App();
    
    EventTarget::addEventListener("generic", &App::onGenericEvent, app);
    Event event("generic", app);
    EventTarget::dispatchEvent(event); // simulate generic event
    
    EventTarget::addEventListener("keydown", &App::onKeyDown, app);  //ERROR: cannot convert 'void (*)(KeyboardEvent)' to std::function<void(Event)>'
    KeyboardEvent keyEvent("keydown", app);                         
    EventTarget::dispatchEvent(keyEvent);  // simulate keydown event
}
```

Online test code: https://onlinegdb.com/uJBz6g4lr

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: First and foremost you are going to slice your `Event` objects if you pass them around by value like that.  You need to pass references or pointers for polymorphism to work!

---

`void(KeyboardEvent&)` is *more specific* than `void(Event&)`, so `std::function<void(Event&)>` cannot wrap a `void(KeyboardEvent&)`.

Consider if it could, then this would be possible:

```
void handler(KeybaordEvent& evt)
{
    std::cout << evt.key;
}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(Event&)> callback(&handler);
    MouseEvent mouseEvent;  // Imagine MouseEvent also derives from Event
    callback(mouseEvent);
}
```

Since a `MouseEvent` is an `Event` a `std::function<void(Event&)>` can accept a `MouseEvent` parameter.  If it was allowed to wrap a `void(KeyboardEvent&)` that would result in the handler being passed the wrong type.  For that reason, what you want is not allowed.

Remember, type checking is done at *compile time*.  Just because you (try to) never pass the wrong type by checking the `EventObject`'s `type` member at runtime doesn't mean you can have mismatched types at compile time.

---

There are two ways to deal with this:

1. Have all of your handlers accept an `Event` and do a runtime check that they got the type of event that they were expecting (i.e. using `dynamic_cast`).
2. Use templates to ensure at compile time that you always pass the correct type of event to the correct handler.

As an example of the second option, you could so something like this:

```
template <typename EventType>
struct EventObject {
    std::string type;
    std::function<void(EventType)> listener;
    void* pointer;
};

class EventTarget {
public:
    template <typename EventType>
    static void addEventListener(std::string type, std::function<void(EventType)> listener, void* pointer){
        EventObject<EventType> eventObj;
        eventObj.type = type;
        eventObj.listener = listener;
        eventObj.pointer = pointer;
        events<EventType>.push_back(eventObj);
    }
    
    template <typename EventType>
    static void dispatchEvent(EventType event){
        for (auto& eventObj : events<EventType>) {
            eventObj.listener(event);
        }
    }
    
    template <typename EventType>
    static std::vector<EventObject<EventType>> events;
};

template <typename EventType>
std::vector<EventObject<EventType>> EventTarget::events;


class KeyboardEvent : public Event {
public:
    KeyboardEvent(std::string _type, void* _pointer) : Event(_type, _pointer) {
        key = "random key";
    }
    std::string key;
};


class App
{
public:
    static void onGenericEvent(Event event) {
        printf("event.type = %s \n", event.type.c_str());
    }
    
    static void onKeyDown(KeyboardEvent event) {
        printf("event.type = %s \n", event.type.c_str());  // print Event class property
        printf("event.key = %s \n", event.key.c_str());    // print KeyboardEvent class property
    }
};


int main() {
    App* app = new App();
    
    EventTarget::addEventListener<Event>("generic", &App::onGenericEvent, app);
    Event event("generic", app);
    EventTarget::dispatchEvent(event); // simulate generic event
    
    EventTarget::addEventListener<KeyboardEvent>("keydown", &App::onKeyDown, app);  //ERROR: cannot convert 'void (*)(KeyboardEvent)' to std::function<void(Event)>'
    KeyboardEvent keyEvent("keydown", app);                         
    EventTarget::dispatchEvent(keyEvent);  // simulate keydown event
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7af9aa325b4f5af)

This creates separate `events` vectors for each type of event.  Now the compiler can check at compile time that the right type of event will always be passed to each handler.

Comment: I thought I could make the code look "easier and shorter" by cutting my code down to passing by value instead of reference. It put me at a loss with how to approach templates.    Your templated EventType stuct is perfect.  I thank you for observing my rudimentary mistake. I learned a good lesson here.